# How can I find and remove duplicates and keep newest?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file structure that looks roughly as follows:

```
dir1
|--subdir1
   |--file1 (modified date1)
   |--file2 (modified date2)
   |--file3 (modified date1)
|--subdir2
   |--file4 (modified date3)
   |--file5 (modified date4)
   |--file6 (modified date3)
```

The files are music files with slightly different ID3 information, so fdupes does not catch them as duplicates though they are. I would like to run a command from `dir1` that will recurse into each subdirectory, find the max modified date for all files, and then prompt to delete any file that has a modified date older than the max.

Is there a way to do this in linux? The expected output would be:

```
dir1
|--subdir1
   |--file1 (modified date1)
   |--file3 (modified date1)
|--subdir2
   |--file4 (modified date3)
   |--file6 (modified date3)
```

Comment: If the files are not exact duplicates, how do we know one is a duplicate of another? Without this information, your "expected" result is simply unexpected.

Comment: I know they are duplicates because the files were originally organized by ID3 Artist and Album. The reason there are duplicates is that I re-ripped albums using slightly differnt ID3 track information. I have no way programatically to check for actual duplicates, but I know implicitly that they are there.

Answer (score 0):

`stat -c %Y <file>` will give you the time of the last modification of *file* in seconds passed since the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). To find the 'max modified date' (which I assume is the latest modification):

```
for i in `ls -1 subdir1/`; do stat -c %Y subdir1/${i} >> mod_dates.txt;done
latest_mod=`cat mod_dates.txt | sort -nr | head -n 1`
```

To delete older files:

```
for i in `ls -1 subdir1/`; do if [[ `stat -c %Y $i` -lt $latest_mod ]]; then rm subdir1/${i};fi;done
```

Comment: Check first whether `sort -n` gives you an oldest-to-latest, or latest-to-oldest order. In any case, you can reverse it with the `-r` option.

Comment: Indeed, you need the reverse the results of `sort`. I've checked and updated my answer. Also, if you need to do this on more subdirs, you can enclose the whole thing in another for loop, like this: `for j in \`ls -d */\`; do <insert rest of code here>; done` Of course you will have to substitute the references to `subdir1` to `$j`.